# Class bindings in Angular not working properly

Tags: angular, class, binding, command-line-interface

I'm trying to assign two classes to a table row based on specific conditions, but the wrong classes gets assigned to the wrong tr's.

My list.component.html:

```
div class="country_box" *ngIf="cases">
  <div class="container">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control-sm"
      name="search"
      [(ngModel)]="search"
      autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="Search by Country Name"
    />
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3><strong>Country Name: </strong></h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3><strong>Cases: </strong></h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3><strong>Deaths: </strong></h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3><strong>Recovered: </strong></h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr
      *ngFor="let country of cases[1].countries_stat | filter: search"
      [ngClass]="setClass(country)"
    >
      <td>{{ country.country_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.cases }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.deaths }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.total_recovered }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My list.component.ts:

```
setClass(stats) {
//console.log(stats.deaths);
let myClass = {
  negative: stats.deaths > stats.total_recovered,
  positive: stats.deaths < stats.total_recovered,
};
return myClass;
```

}

and finally my list.component.css:

```
    .positive {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.negative {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fafafa;
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You setClass return the object instead of the class name.

can you try to return the class name like below one.

```
setClass(stats) {
    return stats.deaths > stats.total_recovered ? 'negative' : 'positive' ;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the results are the same :(. Many countries with positive recovery rates still gets assigned the negative class.

Comment: then you can add in tr file
 <tr
      *ngFor="let country of cases[1].countries_stat | filter: search"
 [ngClass] = "country.deaths > country.total_recovered ? 'negative': 'positive'">

Comment: Tried that, same effect I'm afraid. You can see why this problem is doing my head in.